# Having trouble with strategy pattern and writing multiple classes to text file

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have multiple classes whose properties need to be written to a text file. Since each class has different properties each requires a different algorithm to write. I'm trying to use a strategy pattern for this but it doesn't seem to be working out - don't know if this is even the correct pattern to use?

```
class A 
{
    void one;
    void two;
    void three;
}

class B
{
    void four;
    void five;
    void six;
    void seven;
}

class C
{
    void eight;
    void nine;
}
```

This is where im having trouble with my design, how would I pass the object into the concrete strategy?

```
class DataParser
{
    Object object;

    void DataParser(Object object)
    {
        this.object = object;

        parsers.put(new ClassA(), new ClassAParser());
        parsers.put(new ClassB(), new ClassBParser());
        parsers.put(new ClassC(), new ClassCParser());
    }

    void writeData()
    {
        ParserInterface parser = parsers.get(this.object);
        /*
         * classAParser.setClassA(object);
         * classBParser.setClassB(object);
         * classCParser.setClassC(object):
        */
        parser.write();
    }
}
```

.

```
interface ParserInterface
{
    void write();
    void read();
}
```

.

```
class ClassAParser()
{
    ClassA classA;

    void setClassA(ClassA classA)
    {
        this.classA = classA;
    }

    void write()
    {
        PrinterWriter writer = new PrintWriter("ClassA.txt");

        writer.printLn(this.classA.getOne() + "|" + this.classA.getTwo() + "|" + this.classA.getThree());

        writer.close();
    }

    void read()
    {
    }
}
```

.

```
class ClassBParser()
{
    ClassB classB;

    void setClassB (ClassB classB )
    {
        this.classB = classB ;
    }

    void write()
    {
        PrinterWriter writer = new PrintWriter("ClassB.txt");

        writer.printLn(this.classB.getFour() + "|" + this.classB.getFive() + "|" + this.classB.getSix() + "|" + this.classB.getSeven());

        writer.close();
    }

    void read()
    {
    }
}
```

So then I can just simply do something like this:

```
class Test()
{
    void testClassA()
    {
        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.setOne("One");
        classA.setTwo("Two");
        classA.setThree("Three");

        DataParser parser = new DataParser(classA);
        parser.writeData();
    }
}
```

Then the ClassA.txt should have the following: "one|two|three"

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish here? Why not use regular Java serialization or XStream?

Comment: @chrylis Can't use those because the text files need to be readable

Comment: What does "readable" mean? Really, we can't offer suggestions on good design without knowing what you're trying to get done.

Comment: @chrylis e.g. ClassA.txt needs to show as "one|two|three"

Answer (score 1):

I think the strategy interface might be a little overkill for what you are trying to achieve. An interface will probably get you what you want:

```
public interface Writable {
  void writeTo(PrintWriter writer);
}

class A implements Writable {
  String one;
  String two;
  String three;

  public void writeTo(PrintWriter writer) {
    // do the writing here
  }
}
```

Repeat for `ClassB` and `ClassC`...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a long shot , 
i have seen in your code the following:

```
  parsers.put(new ClassA(), new ClassAParser());
```

but i cannot find where you declare this variable (i guess is wrong copy-paste)
Anyway, i assume that you use a HashMap because of the method put().
If this is the case you need to implement both equals() and hashCode() in the classes A,  B, C.
see here why

[Understanding the workings of equals and hashCode in a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894377/understanding-the-workings-of-equals-and-hashcode-in-a-hashmap)

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html

(in short words if you don't override these methods then the object you pass in the

```
       parsers.get(this.object);
```

should be the exact same instance with the one of the objects you have putted in your map but in your case it is not)

Comment: I think this is not a good advice, it would make `equals` and `hashCode` behave in a very unusual and surprising way. What he probably meant was something like `parsers.put(ClassA.class, new ClassAParser());`

Comment: @Flavio Anything you use as key in a HashMap should override equals and hashcode. From that point of view is a good advice. But i totally agree with you in the second part. it seems that what he really wanted to do is to use ClassA.class as a key

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generic interface for the parser.

```
public interface ParserInterface<T> {
    void setObject(T object);
    void read();
    void write();
}

public class ClassAParser implements ParserInterface<ClassA> { ... }
```

As Pitelk mentioned, the map of object and parser seems wrong. Instead you'll want to use a map of class to parser:

```
parsers.add(ClassA.class, new ClassAParser());
// etc.
```

Besides: creating instances of all parser implementations in the constructor of `DataParser` is unnecessary overhead. You could create only the needed instance using an `if` / `else if` chain and `Object.getClass` or `instanceof` in the constructor or make the map a static member of your class.

`writeData` then becomes:

```
void <T> writeData()
{
    ParserInterface<T> parser = (ParserInterface<T>) parsers.get(this.object.getClass());
    parser.setObject((T) this.object);  // <-- same method for all of supported types
    parser.write();
}
```

The compiler will generate a warning about unchecked casts. But if used correctly, i.e. `parsers.get(c)` returns a compatible parser, it can be ignored or suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same mode as described in [Java: If-else instanceof extended classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897791/java-if-else-instanceof-extended-classes/18911983#18911983) if you don't want to let your class implements an interface. To factory class you have to pass object to write and where to write.
Another way can be to use a template method pattern in this way:

```
abstract class ParserReaderWriter implements ParserInterface {
  protected abstract String[] getDataToWrite();
  protected abstract PrintWriter createWriter();
  void write() {
    Writer writer = createWriter();

    writer.println(StringUtils.join(getDataToWrite(),"|");
    writer.close();
  }
}
```

then create a writer for all writer

```
class AParserReaderWriter extends ParserReaderWriter {
  ClassA object;
  AParserReaderWriter(ClassA object) {
    this.object = object;
  }
  protected String[] getDataToWrite() {
    return new String[]{this.object.getOne(),...};
  }
  protected PrintWriter createWriter() {
    return new PrintWriter("a.txt");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need for a "strategy", here (at least that sounds too heavy-weight for me in this case). Also, I wouldn't "map" anything explicitly here.

So basically I've understood that you'll have objects of the given classes at some time in your application, and then want to create text files in a format defined freely by yourself. This is perfectly valid as a requirement, so I won't point you to any conventions or tools, here. However I also understand that you don't want to do the "serialization" individually within each of the classes, but rather use one (custom) "serializer", probably application-wide. This is where my suggestion differs from other answers.

The method which will actually create the text files needs at least these pieces of information:

1. the object(s) actually containing the property values
2. what properties there are (or even: which ones are actually to be considered)
3. the (base) name of the file to write to - and the character encoding to use, or, more generally, a Writer, or whatever fits your specific requirements on this aspect.

My personal approch would thus be to implement a Util method being as specific as allowed in your case, and as generic as needed to avoid duplicate code.

Within that method, I'd iterate (using reflection) over either:

- all accessible (or even all declared) fields
- all *annotated* fields

For the latter variant you'll need to implement your own Annotation to mark the desired properties, or just use the existing "@Transient" annotation to sort out the non-wanted ones. Wait, you'll certainly want the annotation to have `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`:

```
//...
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
public @interface MyAnnotation
//...
```

But maybe you don't even need to explicitly mark or select properties, particularly if your classes are purely value-holding.

Once you've accessed a given property within the suggested loop, simply make use of String.valueOf (ex- or implicitly) to send the "contents" of that property to a writer, or append to a file directly.

Java serialization generally aims to descend further in object "trees", since any of your properties may be a complex object of its own, requiring more or less sophisticated serialization again.

But I've understood that you rather need a simple, "flat" solution here.